# Asp.NET Core Model Binding input type checkbox not remains unchecked

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, checkbox

I am facing some strange issue, I am using Asp.net Core.

I have Model class which I am binding to my razor view and here is the model implementation.

```
        {
            PatientDetailReport = new ReportModel();
            itemid = true;
        }
public ReportModel PatientDetailReport { get; set; }
        public bool itemid { get; set; }
```

Report Model Class has few bool properties like
`public bool IdentityNumberDisplay { get; set; }`

I am trying to bind model in both of these ways as mentioned by mostly blogs and also on stackoverflow

```
      (1) <input type="checkbox"  asp-for="@Model.PatientDetailReport.IdentityNumberDisplay"   />
     (2)  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.PatientDetailReport.IdentityNumberDisplay,new { })
    </td>
```

but both of these cases remains unchecked.

for first case, I also tried with `value=@Model.PatientDetailReport.IdentityNumberDisplay`
but at jquery level I have to check it with value =True or False (as string) I am able to modify the checkbox, but the value is not posting on Controller.

Please can anyone guide me regarding to this case.
Why the case 2 is not working,however most of the blogs are saying to use like that?

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry about Title of this question got wrong, It is "Checkboxes remains Unchecked"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue using JQuery by checking Checkbox value from Model which is coming as 'True' in string format, and then assigned checked property to true.

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.PatientDetailReport.IdentityNumberDisplay
   ,new {value=Model.PatientDetailReport.IdentityNumberDisplay })
```

```
 $.each($("input[type='checkbox']"), function (e) {
                console.log($(this).val());
                //debugger;
                if ($(this).val() === 'True') {
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                }

            })
```

I am not sure it is correct or not but this resolved my issue for asp.net core model's bool property for checkbox or radio button.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your problem, make sure `PatientDetailReport.IdentityNumberDisplay` has been set to `true` in your case.

Since your code does not assign value to it and the default value `false` results in checkbox unchecked.

You could set default value like below to have a test:

`public bool IdentityNumberDisplay { get; set; } = true;`

```
<form method="post">
    @Model.PatientDetailReport.IdentityNumberDisplay
    @*see the value of IdentityNumberDisplay*@

    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.PatientDetailReport.IdentityNumberDisplay" />
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.PatientDetailReport.IdentityNumberDisplay,new { })

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I have checked and run this code in debug mode, and the value is true, for this property.  In fact for test purpose  I am setting itemid=true at constructor level and it is also showing unchecked.